# sessionStorage doesn't clear after browser restart

Tags: javascript, browser

`sessionStorage` is supposed to be cleared after the browser is restarted, [according to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage):

> data stored in sessionStorage gets cleared when the page session ends

I restart and restart Firefox 59 and Chrome 65 — and nothing, `sessionStorage`'s data is still there. Why would that be?

Comment: Like `select`, Firefox and Chrome are not broken. *("Not broken" background: https://pragprog.com/the-pragmatic-programmer/extracts/tips)*. Show us the code that you think is demonstrating that session storage is not getting cleared, and we'll tell you what's wrong with it. (Edit: Just tested to be absolutely sure, and both Chrome and Firefox dropped the values I put in session storage when they were expected to -- of course.)

Comment: Testet in Firefox, using the option "Restore last session" restores `sessionStorage`.

Comment: @RolandStarke: Well, sure, if you explicitly use a browser feature that says it restores the last session, it restores the last session. That's not what the OP describes. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder :) I bet that this is the problem OP is having :D. (idk i don't use sync, but maybe if you do, your sessions never end)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I open devtools > Application > Session Storage > *current_site*, double click under existed table values, enter new entry like key is `test`, value is `qwe`, close browser, open it again -- the entry is still here.
The same if I create entry by console like `sessionStorage.setItem('test', 'qwe');`
The same in Firefox.

Comment: @totalamd: It being visible if you dive into the browser's list of what it has stored is not the same as it not expiring. It's entirely within spec if Firefox doesn't clear that data until you next request it and it says "Oh, this data is obsolete -- we'll throw it out and start fresh." Or if it doesn't even do that. So long as `sessionStorage.getItem("test")` doesn't return `"qwe"` when you call it in a fresh session, it's in-spec. So again: Post the code that you think demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Ok, I open console, execute `sessionStorage.setItem('test', 123)`, restart the browser, run `sessionStorage.getItem('test')` and get `123` -- what I do wrong?

Comment: @totalamd: What page are you going to when you do that? Is there any *other* code on the page? Are you using some kind of sync as suggested by Roland Starke above? It certainly doesn't happen with a normally-configured Chrome or Firefox on (say) this page.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Created new Firefox profile, turned out *show tabs&windows from last time* saves `sessionStorage`.

Comment: @totalamd: Yes, because you're continuing the same session. The MDN page you linked even says that: *"A page session lasts for as long as the browser is open **and survives over** page reloads and **restores**."*

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5141331/firefox-3-6-sessionstorage-persists-between-browser-sessions and

Comment: So `sessionStorage` practically have no sense bcs many people use session restoration?

Comment: Facing same issues @totalamd :'( While chrome seems to fixed this issue, now for me at least it is not keeping the sessionStorage values, but firefox is. And this is very bad for me currently.

Comment: @Sanuj nope, Chrome still stores sessionStorage on restarts

Comment: Arguably the browser restart and the end of session are different things. Imagine Android closing the browser to save memory. When the use comes back to the browser via the task menu it gets restarted, but the user expects to continue the session.

Comment: As a Final comment, 
If user has selected the option to continue where he/she left than, Browsers are free to choose if they keep `sessionStorage` or not. Generally they all keep it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For those who are wondering and here. If user has selected to continue where he left option of similar feature in any browser. `sessionStorage` will be saved by the browser in between the restarts of the browser.

We had to get our requirements changed as because of this. Hope it will be helpful for some